# Python: How do I extract public key from a '.cert' file?

Tags: python, cryptography

I have used openssl to generate a X.509 self-signed like so:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

This generated two files: cert.pem and a key.pem files.

My cert.pem file contains the public key. How do I extract it using Python?
I am unable to use the OpenSSl library of python. I am able to use the cryptography library.
My current code:

```
cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(pem_data, default_backend())
print(cert.public_key)
```

Comment: Show the code please.

Comment: @Roshith

 ```cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(pem_data, default_backend())```
 ```print(cert.serial_number)```
  
Unfortunately, it says pem_data is no defined

Comment: Edit the question to include the full program.  We can't tell much from one line.

Comment: @Maqruis1 please add the complete, executable code block to the question  for people to understand the problem

Comment: *...I am able to use the cryptography library.* ok, then what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you'd do it just the same as you would if you were reading any other file's contents with python.

Something like this should get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(["openssl", "rsa", "-in", "key.pem", "-pubout", "-out", "key.pub"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
p.stdout.readline().rstrip()

pubkey_file=open('key.pub', 'r')
for line in pubkey_file.readlines():
    data=line.strip('\n')
    print(data)
pubkey_file.close()
```

Comment: I did something similar, but when i do ```print(cert.public_key)
``` it prints out ```<bound method _Certificate.public_key of <Certificate(subject=<Name([<NameAttribute(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=2.5.4.6, name=countryName)>, value='AU')>, <NameAttribute(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=2.5.4.8, name=stateOrProvinceName)>, value='Vic')>, <NameAttribute(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=2.5.4.7, name=localityName)>, value='Mel')>, <NameAttribute(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=2.5.4.10, name=organizationName)>, value='Mon')>, <NameAttribute(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=2.5.4.11, name=organsaton...i```

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question at first. I just posted a potential solution as you have access to the `openssl` command. I just tested this out, it works for me to read the contents of the public key. Disregard if this doesn't serve you.