# Could not deserialize key data (RSA). The data may be in an incorrect format

Tags: python, azure, flask, jwt, azure-ad-msal

I have this flask endpoint. But openssl is raising a weird error.

```
import jwt

@app.route('/api/secure')
def secure_endpoint():
    options = {'verify_aud': False, 'require_sub': True}
    access_token = request.headers.get('Authorization').split('Bearer ')[1]
    jwks_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys'
    jwkeys = requests.get(jwks_uri).json()['keys']
    token_key_id = jwt.get_unverified_header(access_token)['kid']
    jwk = [key for key in jwkeys if key['kid'] == token_key_id][0]
    der_cert = b64decode(jwk['x5c'][0])
    cert = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(der_cert, default_backend())
    public_key = cert.public_key()
    pem_key = public_key.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
                                      format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo)
    token_claims = jwt.decode(jwt=access_token, verify=False, key=pem_key,
                              audience=app_config.CLIENT_ID, algorithms=['RS256'], options=options)
    print(token_claims)
```

The error happens at the `jwt.decode(` line.

I tried to add padding `pem_key = pem_key.decode().split('\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n')[0] + '==' + '\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n'` then got below error

```py
ValueError: ('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [_OpenSSLErrorWithText(code=75497572, lib=9, reason=100, reason_text=b'error:0480
```

context: I am tying to verify a token generated by azure AD (MSAL) from angular client. I am not able to decode the token. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

This error also happened with RSA512. The jwt package used is `PyJwt`.

Comment: I have the except same problem

Comment: Can you check if this thread helps "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319582/python-valueerror-could-not-deserialize-key-data", seems to be a similar issue

Comment: @QuintenC Did someone manage to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the token is `idToken`, not `accessToken`, when you are processing the token from AuthenticationResult

```js
export type AuthenticationResult = {
    authority: string;
    uniqueId: string;
    tenantId: string;
    scopes: Array<string>;
    account: AccountInfo | null;
    idToken: string;
    idTokenClaims: object;
    accessToken: string;
    fromCache: boolean;
    expiresOn: Date | null;
    extExpiresOn?: Date;
    refreshOn?: Date;
    tokenType: string;
    correlationId: string;
    requestId?: string;
    state?: string;
    familyId?: string;
    cloudGraphHostName?: string;
    msGraphHost?: string;
    code?: string;
    fromNativeBroker?: boolean;
};
```

---

Just a reminder, after you login through Azure SSO, you will get multiple tokens, and the only token that you need to verify is `idToken`, because its intended for you, and do not verify `accessToken`, that is intended for Microsoft Graph.

I have been trying to validation `accessToken` for days, turns out it is not for us.